# Passenger not passing params hash to Rails application on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, passenger

I have an existing rails application that works well on Passenger for Linux. It works well on a local mongrel instance. The DB is postgresql in all cases. However, when I installed Phusion Passenger 2.2.4 on a spare Mac with OS X Leopard (running 10.5.7), the params hash does not get passed to the underlying rails application. Are there any settings that could help resolve this?

**More details:**
Here is a sample form

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="authenticationkey" value="..." />
<input type="text" name="model[name]" />
<input type="text" name="not_a_param" />
<input type="submit" value="send to server">
</form>
```

So, when the values of this form are sent to the server, the value for '*not_a_param*' appears perfectly in the log, and any dumps of the input. However, when I look for the '*model*' hash, it always shows up as nil.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Rails 2.3.0 and Passenger 2.2.5 on Ubuntu.

I thought it was passenger, but updating to 2.2.8 did nothing.

Found: http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=220, so evidently it is rack related.

Updating to Rails 2.3.4 did the trick.